# Should I initialize the register in x86 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm trying to solve this exercise :

Assume that you are given values in eax,ebx,ecx. Write code that adds the
values inside all those registers, and stores the final result inside edx.

My code :

```
mov eax,3
mov ebx,4
mov ecx,1
add edx,eax
add edx,ebx
add edx,ecx
```

Do I have to initialize the register edx (mov edx,0) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Do I have to initialize the register edx (mov edx,0) ?

The way your code is written you need to clear `edx` prior to the first `add`, either with `mov edx, 0` or `xor edx, edx`. But instead of adding an extra instruction you can just replace the first `add` with a `mov`:

```
mov edx,eax   ; edx = eax
add edx,ebx   ; edx += ebx
add edx,ecx   ; edx += ecx
```

Or, one instruction less:

```
lea edx,[eax + ebx]  ; edx = eax + ebx
add edx,ecx          ; edx += ecx
```

Comment: OP should zero `edx` if he wants to keep using his code, though, so I'd say `Yes, or you can just replace ...`.